# How to access .Net classes from C++/CX?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uwp, c++-cx

I want to use HttpListener class in my UWP C++/CX project.
How can I do it ?
I tried:

```
#using <system.dll>
using namespace System::Net;
HttpListener^ listener = ref new HttpListener();
```

I've got an error:

> fatal error C1114:
>   'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\system.dll': WinRT does
>   not support #using of a managed assembly

Comment: In general, the .NET API is available for C# and VB, it should not be used directly in c ++/cx. In this case, you could try to use [StreamSocketListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener#syntax) to complete functions similar to httplistener.

Comment: But why it is possible to choose C++ on the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.8 ? It tells that the following class exists: "public ref class HttpListener sealed : IDisposable".

Comment: This api isn't supported in UWP. The C++ mentioned above may mean that it can be used in the desktop app using C++. But for the UWP project you created, this API is not available.